# Sorting array by variable number of columns

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

Say I have an array

```
var originalArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

I want to display to apply 
`function orderToColumn (originalArray, numberofcolumn)` to get a return value like so

```
Array [ 1, 4, 7, 2, 5, undefined, 3, 6, undefined ]
```

the point being I want to be able to display my array in the following format:

```
1 4 7
2 5
3 6
```

Heres my attempt so far: https://jsfiddle.net/042o7rv9/
The array could be of any size and the `numberofcolumn>=1`.

Comment: Can you give another example with a longer or a shorter array?

Comment: Does `originalArray` always start with `1` and is it always sorted? In other words, why is there no gap for the missing `0`?

Comment: nah the array could be objects, i used sorted numbers simply for explanation purposes. anyways i figured it out on my own. seemed to be more of an bootstrap/css error when rendering rather than algorithm error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
function orderToColumn(arr,col){
  var len = col*Math.ceil(arr.length / col);
  console.log(len);
  var newArr=[];
  for(var i = 0;i<col;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<len/col;j++){
      newArr.push(arr[j*col+i]);
    }
  }
  return newArr;
}
var b = orderToColumn(a,3);
console.log(b); // [1, 4, 7, 2, 5, undefined, 3, 6, undefined]
```

Answer (score 0):

You might do functionally as follows;

```js
function columnize(a,n){
  var count = Math.ceil(a.length/n);
  return a.reduce((p,c,i) => i%count === 0 ? p.concat([[c]]) : (p[p.length-1].push(c),p),[]);
}

var originalArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
           result = columnize(originalArray,3);
console.log(result);
```